# TYPO3 Solr - faceting by file extension

Tags: solr, typo3, typo3-10.x

TYPO3 10.4.20, Solr 10.0.5, solr_file_indexer 2.3.3.

After indexing my website I have 5 different types

```
pages 
tt_address 
tx_events2_domain_model_event
tx_news_domain_model_news
sys_file_metadata
```

that I use for faceting.

```
plugin.tx_solr.search {
    faceting = 1
    faceting {
        facets {
            contentType {
                label = Content Type
                field = type
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All of my files (*.pdf, *.mp3, *.mp4) have the type `sys_file_metadata`. I'd love to offer faceting by file extension, too. Then the users could find all audio and video files easly.

What is a way to get the following result?

```
pages 
tt_address 
tx_events2_domain_model_event
tx_news_domain_model_news
PDF
MP3
MP4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible out of the box because the field `type` is set to `sys_file_metadata`.

A solution however is quite easy: You need an additional field for the type

```
plugin.tx_solr.index.queue {
  # Set it for pages
  pages.fields {
    customtype_stringS = TEXT
    customtype_stringS.value = pages
  }

  # Set it for news, and all other records
  tx_news_domain_model_news.fields {
    customtype_stringS = TEXT
    customtype_stringS.value = tx_news_domain_model_news
  }
}
```

Now the facet needs to use the new field:

```
plugin.tx_solr.search.faceting.facets.type.field = customtype_stringS
```

---

Use a hook of EXT:solr to add the metadata in your extension:

*ext_localconf.php*

```php
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['solr']['IndexQueueIndexer']['preAddModifyDocuments'][] = \Vendor\Theme\Hooks\Solr\RecordIndexModifier::class;
```

and the code

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Theme\Hooks\Solr;

use ApacheSolrForTypo3\Solr\IndexQueue\Item;
use ApacheSolrForTypo3\Solr\IndexQueue\PageIndexerDocumentsModifier;
use ApacheSolrForTypo3\Solr\System\Solr\Document\Document;

class RecordIndexModifier implements PageIndexerDocumentsModifier
{

    /**
     * @param Item $item
     * @param int $language
     * @param Document[] $documents
     * @return Document[]|array
     */
    public function modifyDocuments(Item $item, int $language, array $documents): array
    {
        $record = $item->getRecord();
        if ($item->getType() === 'sys_file_metadata') {
            foreach ($documents as $k => $document) {
                $this->enrichMetaData($record, $document);
            }
        }

        return $documents;
    }

    protected function enrichMetaData(array $row, Document $document): void
    {
        $document->setField('customtype_stringS', $document->getFields()['fileExtension'] ?? '');
    }

}
```

**Important**: ALL records need to be reindexed to get the new field

Comment: @ringer I followed your advice and got a new field ' customtype_stringS => 'file extension'. Because I don't see any changes in the type filter after reindexing, I'm missing something. Do I have to add something in the last part of the hook? (// your code is missing here)

Comment: I guess it could be

$document->setField('customtype_stringS', $document->getFields()['fileExtension'] ?? '');

Comment: @ringer Following your advice and using customtype_stringS as type field I get the filter option for pages, mp3, mp4 and pdf files now, but not for tt_address, tx_news and events2 because their customtype_stringS fields are empty resp. don't exist.

Comment: what you do with tx_news_domain_model_news in the TS must be done for all other records as well

Comment: I have done it  for all other records as well and it doesn't work for tx_news_domain_model_news, tt_address and tx_events2_domain_model_event.

Comment: you can contact me on slack but it is impossible to help here without any code - not the right place

Comment: Thanks to the great support of Georg Ringer the problem is solved. Probably it was the cache in the end.